# How to avoid my global variable gets reset when i call my function

Tags: c, variables, global

i am a beginner and start to write some simple program.
I want to create a global variable to maintain my record number, unfortunately, my variable reset to zero every time i call my function. I looked into some other sample like people using static or volatile to declare my variable, i tried them both but still resetting my value. Please kindly advise. Thanks.
Please take a look my function below.

```
int record_number;
int file_number;

int Record_Count(int record_correct);
{
   if (record_correct)
      record_number++;
   if (record_number == 100)
   {
      file_number++;
      record_number = 0;
   }

   return record_number;
}
```

Comment: I know, don't use a global variable... The posted code is not enough. You must be doing something else somewhere...

Comment: May need to expand code snippet to show the true scope of those "global" variables.  You should also explicitly initialize them to zero when declaring them.

Comment: @stevesliva,  global variables are already initialized to 0

Comment: Yeah, you need to show more code, also pretty sure what you've shown up there won't work, on account of the stray semi-colon in your function declaration.

Comment: @AlterMann - I know.  Doesn't effect my comment.

Answer (score 2):

As others have commented, it doesn't look like you've pasted your code directly from the editor - instead typing it in from scratch.

That said, I suspect you've fallen afoul of one of the most notorious traps of C that still catches professional programmers occasionally (I've been using the language since the early 80's and I still do it).

Go to your original code and take a very close look at the line you've pasted as

```
if (record_number == 100)
```

Does it actually say this?

```
if (record_number = 100)
```

If so, the `if` statement will be executed every time you call the function because the predicate (`record_number = 100`) first assigns 100 to `record_number` then tests the result to see if it's non-zero (which `100` is, of course) and takes the `if` branch, setting `record_number` to zero (and coincidentally incrementing `file_number`).

The way to avoid this is to develop a coding habit very quickly and then stick to it. Always code equality comparisons against a constant this way:

```
if(100 == record_number)
```

Then, if you mistype the `==` as `=` the compiler will throw an error for you.

Comment: The second favourite trap is posting code that is *something like* the code that malfunctions, when it should be an example that demonstrates the fault.

Comment: yep, but if the OP is truly a newbie to C, this has a high probability of being the cause :) We'll see, and the advice is good for a newbie anyway.

Comment: I agree, let's see. I upvote this, as I have wondered why a test is done that way round: `constant == variable`.